How to count the number of ordered $k$-pairings in binary strings?
Suppose we have a string of length $n$ made of two different symbols, call them $a$ and $b$. I want to count the number of possible "$k$-pairings": configurations of $k$ distinct $ab$ pairs connecting an $a$ and a $b$ on its right.
For example, consider the string $abab$. Then there's (colouring different pairs to distinguish them):

three $1$-pairings: $ab\color{red}{ab}$, $\color{red}{ab}ab$, and $\color{red}
{a}ba\color{red}{b}$.
one $2$-pairing: $\color{red}{ab}\color{blue}{ab}$.

On the other hand for the string $aabb$, there'd be

four 1-pairings $a\color{red}{ab}b$, $a\color{red}{a}b\color{red}{b}$, $\color{red}{a}a\color{red}{b}b$, $\color{red}{a}ab\color{red}{b}$.
two 2-pairings: $\color{red}{a}\color{blue}{a}\color{red}{b}\color{blue}{b}$, $\color{red}{a}\color{blue}{a}\color{blue}{b}\color{red}{b}$.

Note that the colours here have no "identity": they're only used to distinguish between different pairings. It might be more expressive to write them with contraction symbols (a la Wick's theorem), but I'm not sure how to do that here.
I'm interested to know whether there's any "nice" closed formula to count such $k$-pairings for a given string. Devising a recipe to do the count for any given string and $k$ isn't hard: start from the right, have $a$ either match or not match with a $b$ on its right, etc. You can also get recursive formulas etc, but I can't see a general method to obtain closed formulas from those.
The main motivation for the question is that I know that in at least some cases there is a neat closed formula: consider strings of the form $(ab)^n\equiv \underbrace{ab\cdots ab}_n$.
Then the number of $k$-pairings is exactly ${n+1\brace n+1-k}$, where ${n\brace m}$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind, that is, the number of partitions of $n$ elements into $m$ subsets.
I know this from other means: in the context of quantum optics, there is a relatively well-known formula for a normally-ordered expansion of $(a^\dagger a)^n$ with $a,a^\dagger$ annihilation/creation operators:
$$(a^\dagger a)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} a^{\dagger k}a^k,$$
and by Wick's theorem the coefficient of the $k$-th term above amounts to the number of ways to get $k$ pairings of an $a$ and a $a^\dagger$ to its right, that is, essentially the problem as I formulated at the beginning of the question.
Although one can handily verify this identity in different ways, I feel there should be a relatively simple combinatorial way to connect such numbers of $k$-pairings to the number of partitions in a set, though I can't see it right now.
